# cannot retrieve database values while sending json data in url using php

Tags: php, json

i have a following issue in my php.,

i'm sending json object as a parameter in url to my php file ., but here i cannot retrieve database values., the output is simply null ..

my url : test1.php?alb_id={"album_ids":[{"alb_id":"2"},{"alb_id":"4"}]}

my php file:

```
 $album_ids = $_REQUEST['alb_id'];

 $id_list_array = json_decode($album_ids);

 $id_array = $id_list_array->album_ids;

 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($id_array);$i++)
 {
    $alb_id = $id_array[$i]->alb_id; 
    $album_sel_query = "SELECT a.a_id as id,a.a_name as name,round((b.total_value/b.total_votes),1) as rating,b.total_votes,b.total_value,a.a_pic as image,c.b_name FROM _album a inner join ratings b on b.id=a.a_id INNER JOIN _band c on c.b_id=a.b_id where a.a_id='".$alb_id."' "; 
    $result = mysql_query($album_sel_query);
    if (!$result)
      die("mySQL error: ". mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 0)
    {
      while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
         $alb_name =$data['name'];  
         $singer = $data['b_name'];   
         $rating = $data['rating'];   
         $rate_value = $data['total_value'];      
         $rate_votes = $data['total_votes'];
         $alb_pic =$data['image']; 
         $resmsg[] = array("Album_id"=>$alb_id,"Album_name"=>$alb_name,"Album_singer"=>$singer,"Album_rating"=>$rating,"Rating_total_value"=>$rate_value,"Rating_total_votes"=>$rate_votes,"Album_image_name"=>$alb_pic);

      }

      $jsonarr = array("response"=>array("success"=>"Y","ALBUM_DETAILS"=>$resmsg));
   }
   else
   {
     $jsonarr = array("response"=>array("success"=>"N","ALBUM_DETAILS"=>"Data not found"));
   }
 }
 echo json_encode($jsonarr);
```

how can i get proper results?

Comment: What does `var_dump($id_list_array)` show?

Comment: thanks for reply,. it showa NULL..

Comment: That means `$album_ids` doesn't contain valid JSON. Are you URL-encoding the JSON before putting it in the URL?

Comment: no i dint encode tat json data .. what shall i do now?

Comment: Encode it properly in the application that creates the URL. If it's Javascript, use `encodeURIComponent`. If it's PHP, use `urlencode`. If it's jQuery AJAX, use an object for the parameters and it will encode it.

Comment: sorry i'm new to json., can u explain some more wher i ve to use urlencode?

Comment: Please post the code that creates the URL, and I'll show how to modify it.

Comment: i don ve anymore code,. i'm having only this file. while running i ll send this url static

Comment: Why are you putting JSON in your URL in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You need to percent-encode special characters in URLs. Change it to:

```
test1.php?alb_id=%7B%22album_ids%22%3A%5B%7B%22alb_id%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%7B%22alb_id%22%3A%224%22%7D%5D%7D
```

I got this by simply running the PHP script:

```
<?php
echo urlencode('{"album_ids":[{"alb_id":"2"},{"alb_id":"4"}]}');
```

Comment: @barmar- couldn't u find my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the first `=` shouldn't be encoded. Try the correction I just made.

Comment: Wow, you're impatient. It's almost 3am here, I could have gone to bed.